# MVC Form View vs Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to migrate a couple of applications one a classic asp app that uses vbscript and RDS datafactory and a foxpro desktop app to MVC.  Is there an example somewhere that shows using jQuery to show the Form View as the startup as opposed to a Table/Grid View with a search.  Both applications show the entire row using the entire screen with Add Update Delete Find Next Prev etc as navigation at the bottom of the screen opposed to the Grid and then edit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes it is a lot, http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/
if can take a look to [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/) or [kendoui](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html) or [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)